# Visual Studio 2017 Cordova & Android

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2017

Looks like Visual Studio do not support beyond Cordova 6.3.1 and Android 25

Any manual installations of cordova 8 and android 26 in VS 2017 loosing its configuration of all installations of build tools required for build and deploy.

It is only maintaining configuration for default whatever comes through VS installer.

Any directions from anybody in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

The longer you use **VS2017**, the more **Cordova** related issues you'll find.

Supposedly, VS2017 allows using your own, globally-installed Cordova version, like **7.1.0**. But it seems the Microsoft developers never actually tested it, therefore this introduces all kind of issues, like the inability of deploying to emulator or the error of lost Cordova Toolset versions you get after changing the toolset with the provided select box in the designer.

**To permanently change the Toolset**, manually edit config.xml following the instructions here: [The selected toolset is not saved](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/#toolset_forgotten).

Notice that by changing your ANDROID_HOME setting from VS2017 to build with Android API26 or newer, your [Deploy to Emulator options will be gone](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/#android_home).

You won't get any of these errors when returning to **VS2015**, which I keep using for now.